# Pagination problem makes data table not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables, pagination

Please help,

I have problem with a data table. The data table does not work when I use this but it's working when it's outside of this. Please help:

```
<div id="content">
       <?php
          $pages_dir = 'pages/admin';
          if(!empty($_GET['p'])){
             $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
             unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);
             $p = $_GET['p'];
          if(in_array($p.'.php', $pages)){
             include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.php');
             } 
          else {
            echo 'Page Not Found :(';
             }
               } 
          else {include($pages_dir.'/profile.php');}
       ?>
</div>
```

Then the other full script page, in this page data table is not working, but when I try this outside code before, it works.

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "keep");  
$query ="SELECT * FROM barang ORDER BY ID DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container">  
            <h3 align="center">Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</h3>  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                      <thead>  
                           <tr>  
                                <td>ID</td>  
                                <td>Nama</td>  
                                <td>Kategori</td>  
                                <td>Harga</td>  
                                <td>Jumlah</td> 
                                <td>Supplier</td>  
                           </tr>  
                      </thead>  
                      <?php  
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                      {  
                           echo '  
                           <tr>  
                                <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["nama"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["kategori"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["harga"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["jumlah"].'</td> 
                                <td>'.$row["supplier"].'</td> 
                           </tr>  
                           ';  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </body>  
</html>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#employee_data').DataTable();  
});  
</script>
```

Please help, I'm new to PHP programming. Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: i didn't see any datatables. and please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ask the question

Comment: sorry for not giving full information , my bad. thanks for giving me advise

Comment: Are you getting any error on DevTools console?